# How can I implement a jump mechanism for the square, triggered by a space key press, without simply teleporting the square upward?

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple JavaScript code that animates a black square, with gravity pulling it downward until it reaches a certain y-value. I am now trying to implement a jump mechanism, whereby pressing the space bar causes the square to jump. Rather than simply teleporting the square upward, I want to achieve a bouncy effect by reversing the square's velocity or using an alternative method. Once the square reaches its peak, gravity should bring it back down to the ground.

this was my attempted implementation:

```
var square = document.createElement("div");
square.style.width = "50px";
square.style.height = "50px";
square.style.position = "absolute";
square.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2 - square.offsetWidth / 2)/2 + "px";
square.style.top = (window.innerHeight / 2 - square.offsetHeight / 2)/2 + "px";
square.style.backgroundColor = "black";
document.body.appendChild(square);

var gravity = 10;
var velocity = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === " " || event.key === "Spacebar") {
    velocity = -30;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      velocity += gravity;
      gravity += .25;
      square.style.top = (window.innerHeight / 2 - square.offsetHeight / 2)/2 + velocity + "px";
  
      if (square.offsetTop + square.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight-100) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        velocity = 0;
      }
    }, 1000 / 120);
  }
});
```

However, the square is currently stuck in its initial position and, upon pressing the space key, it simply teleports back to its original position with increased gravity applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I changed it too much from your original code, but it was fun. Maybe you can find something useful there.

Changing "gravitation" makes keeping track of the reversed the motion difficult.

Also, there is a roundoff error that tends to decrease the energy each time the cube returns to the same point (even in absence of damping), so I decided to control the energy at the "bottom" through a special variable `velocityReversed`.

```js
var square = document.createElement("div");
square.style.width = "50px";
square.style.height = "50px";
square.style.position = "absolute";
square.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2 - square.offsetWidth / 2)/2 + "px";
square.style.top = "50px";
square.style.backgroundColor = "black";
document.body.appendChild(square);

var baseLine = document.createElement("div");
baseLine.style.width = "100vw";
baseLine.style.height = "100px";
baseLine.style.position = "absolute";
baseLine.style.left = "0";
baseLine.style.bottom = "0";
baseLine.style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";
baseLine.style.borderTop = "#888 1px solid";
document.body.appendChild(baseLine);


var gravity = 10;
var velocity = 0;
var velocityReversed = 0;
var maxLoops = 100, currentLoop = 0;
var y0 = window.innerHeight - 100 - square.offsetHeight - square.offsetTop;
var y = 0;

function setElementAtY(el, y){
    if(y < 0){
        y = 0;
    }
    el.style.top = window.innerHeight - 100 - square.offsetHeight - y + "px";
}

setElementAtY(square, y0);
var intervalId = null;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {    
        if (event.key === "Escape" && intervalId !== null) {
        clearInterval(intervalId); intervalId = null;
    }
    else if ((event.key === " " || event.key === "Spacebar") && intervalId === null) {
        if(y <= 0) { // relaunch
            y0 = window.innerHeight - 100 - square.offsetHeight - 50;
            y = y0;
            setElementAtY(square, y);
            velocity = 0;//-5;
            velocityReversed = 0;
        }
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            dt = 0.1; // for realism, i.e., slower
            velocity -= gravity * dt;
            y += velocity * dt;
            setElementAtY(square, y);
            if (y <= 0 || y > y0) {
                if(y <= 0){
                    if(++currentLoop > maxLoops){
                        clearInterval(intervalId); intervalId = null;
                        velocity = 0;
                        currentLoop = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(velocityReversed === 0){
                            velocityReversed = -velocity;
                        }
                        velocityReversed *= 0.92; // damped (>1 faster)
                        if(velocityReversed < 1){
                            clearInterval(intervalId); intervalId = null;
                        }
                        velocity = velocityReversed;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    velocity = -velocity;
                }
            }
        }, 1000 / 120);
    }
});
```

```html
Go full page - Space to run, Esc to pause
```